# Responsive 2 Column Layout With Embedded Video

Tags: html, css

I have a **two column** section on a homepage, with a responsive video.

The goal is to get the **text in absolute center** on the **left** column, and have the **video take up 100%** of the **righ**t column but have it be responsive.

I have achieved this somewhat.... But the video **height shrinks** and eventually the right column is smaller then the left.

I still need to add media queries to fix the text at certain points, but I have no idea what to do with the video.

```css
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;

}


.right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
.group:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .left, 
    .right {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }
}

.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.financingBlock{

    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    position: relative;
}

.financingText{
    padding:90px 0 0 104px;   
}

.financingText p{
line-height: 30px; 
font-size: 14px;
padding-right:70px;
}
.clearer {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="financingBlock">
        <div class="left">
                  <div class="financingText">

                        <p>SLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam condimentum luctus ex, at bibendum dolor feugiat vel. Mauris sit amet ante interdum, varius nibh vitae, condimentum nunc.</p>

                      <p>usce posuere tempus tempus. Sed nec nibh justo. Vestibulum nec eleifend libero, tempus elementum quam. Nulla a facilisis sem, vitae imperdiet diam. Pellentesque faucibus porta facilisis. Vestibulum quis augue a nunc euismod hendrerit. </p>

                   </div>

                </div>
      <div class="right">
                    <div class="videoWrapper">
                        <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
                        <iframe width="560" height="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nDY8b68oLA0?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>                             </iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>

  <div class="clearer"></div>

</div>
```

[image: GOOD]

[image: OKAY]

[image: BAD]

Comment: The text  is centered and video takes full width,so both works fine and. Can you explain it more what you want?

Comment: If you see the third image of a smaller screen, the text goes below the video it should be similar to the pictures one and two of bigger screens.

Comment: This is for range 1200px to 550px, so you need to need adjust the responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have given a static padding for each screen size 
like:

```
.financingText{padding:90px 0 0 104px;}
```

instead use:

```
.financingText{padding:0;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;margin:0auto;}
```

Comment: this isn't really centering the text (velnikolic.com/alohaSpeed)

Comment: have u removed the padding of the <p> tag also?

Comment: .financingText p {
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-right: 70px;
}

Comment: plz change it to padding: 0 auto;

Comment: I assume you meant remove the padding and add a margin of 0 auto?
the p elements still seem unaffected and are not in the absolute middle (vertical + horizontal)